# Keyboard / touchpad not working on startup

Tags: keyboard, startup, trackpad

I dual boot MacOS and Ubuntu on a Macbook Pro and used to be able to switch between the two by holding the Option button on startup.

Recently this has stopped working; the keyboard and touchpad are unresponsive on startup and so Ubuntu boots by default. Once Ubuntu loads, the keyboard and touchpad work as normal.

Using an USB keyboard, I can hold down Option and choose to boot into MacOS. However, the internal keyboard and touchpad remain unresponsive when I reach the login screen (and after logging in etc).

Without the USB keyboard, I can't even reset the PRAM or boot into recovery mode. I have reset the PRAM using the USB keyboard, but this hasn't solved the issue.

I've also changed the boot order so that MacOS boots by default on startup, however this hasn't solved the issue either.

I'd be really grateful for any suggestions to get the Macbook Pro to recognise the internal keyboard and touchpad on startup.

Edit: I'm using a Macbook Pro, Retina, 13-inch, late 2013

Comment: What model/year is your MBP?  Is it a touchbar model?

Comment: @lx07 late 2013, no touchbar